# How to not expose base64 encoded UUIDs

Tags: database, rest, security, base64, uuid

I have a doubt regarding the exposure of internal database primary keys.
I have decided to use `UUIDs` in place of auto-increment longs (see [here](https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439) for details). This way, among other things, people cannot discover the relative size of my data or their growth over time.

Now, the `UUID` doesn't provide any internal information but it is not very URL friendly, although it is URL safe. Furthermore if long PKs shouldn't be exposed, then `UUIDs` shouldn't either.
Usually to make `UUIDs` more user friendly, people `base64` encode them.
Example:

```
 - UUID: 7b3149e7-bdab-4895-b659-a5f5b0d0
 - base64: ezFJ572rSJW2WQAApfWw0A
```

My point is: anyone could still take those `base64` string from the url and decode them in order to obtain the original `UUID`. This means that even in this case `UUIDs` would end up being exposed as well.

Should I use another type of encoding? Is out there something already known or should I create my custom encoding? If yes, should I follow any guidelines?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you care? What is your threat model?

Comment: @SLaks I am developing a shopping cart website and I am trying to design it taking care of future problems. Many blogs online say that db ids shouldn't be exposed; but even if they replace auto-increment ids with uuids and encode them, they are definitively exposing them. So I got this doubt. Shouldn't I really care of it?

Comment: Simply using another encoding is just obfuscation (security by obscurity). You didn't answer @SLaks question. What threat do you wish to eliminate? "Many blogs online say that db ids shouldn't be exposed." Why do they say that?

Answer (score 2):

On the first look to be able to provide a small tiny level of Secrecy to those Identifiers you can use one way Hash functions such as SHA2(which is a Cryptographic function and not Encoding). This will literally buy you no specific security advantage.

If you are relying only on Object Reference IDs for access control and try to make them secret then I suggest you think twice at your Access Control and Authorization Model. 
It is good to have random/non-guessable/Collision Free Object Reference IDs, however If you are relying on Secrecy of Reference ID for security this is a big flaw (in Old OWASP Top10 this was referred as Direct Object Reference Identifier Issue and in OWASP 2017 this is referred as Broken Access Control Issue). You need to consider a Full AAA chain: Authentication,Authorization,Audit/Accountability for Access by relying on a Random unique Token with a short validity period, which later on can be used to decide on Authorization and Access levels of your system's to be tied with a subject and permit them to interact with the Objects that they are entitled with.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't supposed to expose PKs is that they may (a) leak information and (b) allow people to guess other values. Neither is true of UUIDs (at least v3/4/5), which is one of the main reasons to use them in the first place. The human factor you mention is why so many folks use base64 (or other) encoding; it's not for security.

That said, you should *never* rely on URL secrecy as security; there are far too many ways that URLs leak, and your users may even do it intentionally--but they'd be very upset if sending a link to their friend meant that friend had full access to their account.